# How to load class files outside workspace in an Eclipse RCP project

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

Is there a way in Eclipse RCP that i can load class files outside the workspace and make them into IJavaProject? Or IResource?

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse 3.3 there is support for external files as well, see this [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_on_a_file_outside_the_workspace%3F).